# Creating Global variables in Visual C#

Tags: c#, variables, global

I'm aware that global variables in most cases are not a good idea (especially in OOP), but I have a need where I need to create an array that can be read by any function or class within my application (basically, the array will store data that I'd only like to have to read once from my MySQL database).

It was suggested that I create a "Variables" class, but the problem I see with that is that I'd have to make a "public" (or global) instance of that class anyway, so creating a class doesn't really solve my problem from what I can see (I could be wrong, though).

How can I create a global variable array that can be seen by all classes and methods?

Answer (score 4):

You want a static class.

```
public static class Global
{
   public static string[] GlobalArray { get; set; } 

   static Global()
   {
       GlobalArray =  //etc  
   }
}
```

which can be accessed from anywhere via :

```
var x = Global.GlobalArray;
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a global variable in C#, but you can create static classes with static properties.

```
public static class Global
{
   public static string[] MyGlobalArray{ get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern):

```
public class Variables
{
  private static Variables instance = new Variables();

  public static Variables Instance
  {
    get
    {
      return instance;
    }
  }

  public string[] GlobalArray { get; set; } 
}

// Usage
var myGlobalArray = Variables.Instance.GlobalArray;
```

See also:

- [Implementing Singleton in C# (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)
- [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C# (C# in Depth)](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx)

Comment: This does not compile. You cannot instantiate a static class.

Comment: @lukegravitt, I updated my example, now it's compiling.